# Integrating pump curve in Modellica.Fluid.Machines.ControlledPump

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm a new user of OpenModelica. I'm trying to initialise variable-speed hydraulic pump curves in Modelica. I have 15 volumetric flow rates (m3/h) and 15 pump heads (m) for **each** pump speed (rev/min). I have been trying to use the following code for inputting these values into my model.

```
redeclare function flowCharacteristic =
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (V_flow_nominal={},head_nominal={})
```

I encounter a translation error because the read-only system library only allows 3 elements in the V_flow_nominal and head_nominal array.

1. How do I obviate the error and still enter all data points I have?
2. How do I convert to SI units (m3/s and Pa)?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `flowCharacteristic` to `Modelica.Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PumpCharacteristics.polynomialFlow` should solve your problem for one speed. Values for other speeds are interpolated from this set of values. If you want to enter different values for other speeds you need a map-based model.